# Divide by zero error with cast when included in a group by

Tags: sql

I am having an issues with a SQL error at the moment, here is my calculation;

```
,   CAST(ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PASS' then [Total Cost] END)             
/               
    SUM([Total Cost]),2) as DECIMAL(10,2))
```

This calculation is included as a group by query, it works without a break-down but has issues when executed to be along different years / months etc.

I believe some kind of nullif or isnull would be the correct answer here but i seem unable to find the right way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks M

Comment: Put the divisor in a `nullif` like `/ NULLIF(SUM([Total Cost]), 0)`

Comment: You mean like this? It still doesn't work. CAST(ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PASS' then [Total Cost] END)    
/    
 NULLIF(SUM([Total Cost]),2),0) as DECIMAL(10,2))

Comment: No that's not what I said. The `,2` is for the `ROUND` not for the `NULLIF` so it's in the wrong place. You need `CAST(ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PASS' then [Total Cost] END) / NULLIF(SUM([Total Cost]), 0), 2) as DECIMAL(10,2))` If you'd space out your brackets you would see what I mean.